# About matlab and printing

Tags: printf

Anyone out there whom could help me understand this in matlab:

I have a struct for a person:
struct(name, bob,
birth,[1x1struct],
number,35167854)

Where birth is:
struct(day, 20,
month, 5,
year, 1990,)

Now have a function that can take in date of birth and it prints out(called "print_date"); 20.5.1990

But then I want a function that prints out the entire person(name, birth, number). So I made a function which goes

fprintf('%d, %d, %d\n',person.name, print_date(person.date_of_birth), person.number)

But I only get the error message: "too many output arguments".
Could anyone be as kind as to help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

`print_date` is not provided nor are the types of data in this struct fully clear, but the `%d` format option is for decimal formatting.  Do you really mean to be formatting `person.name` and the result of `print_date` as decimals?  I cannot say for sure without seeing your code whether `person.name` is a number, but it does not seem likely.

Try formatting them as `%s`